# Idea about the projections of the $C^*$-algebra $pAp$, where $p$ is a projection in $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $p$ be a projection in $A$. Now consider the $C^*$-algebra $pAp$. I want to classify the projections in $pAp.$ I know that, if $q \in A$ is a projection such that $pq=qp$, then $pqp$ is a projection in $pAp$, that is
$$(pqp)^*=pq^*p=pqp~~\text{ and }~~ (pqp)(pqp)=pqpqp=pqp.$$
Now I want to know, how the projections in $pAp$ looks like$?$ If we consider $P(A)$ and $P(pAp)$ be the set of all projections in $A$ and $pAp$ respectively, then it is clear that $\{pqp:q \in P(A),~ pq=qp\} \subseteq P(pAp)$. But is the other direction is true, that is, $\{pqp:q \in P(A),~ pq=qp\} = P(pAp)?$ Please help me to see the set $P(pAp)$. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $x\in pAp$ is of the form
$$x=pyp$$
hence satisfies
$$px=p^2yp=pyp=pyp^2=xp.$$
Moreover, we have
$$pxp=p^2yp^2=pyp=x.$$
Hence every $x\in P(pAp)$ is of the form $x=pqp$ for some $q\in P(A)$ such that $pq=qp:$ take $q:=x$ itself.

Comment: Thank you. But my question is, when we can say $q$ as a projection in $pAp?$

Comment: @abcdmath thank you, I think we can delete all our comments now.

Comment: @abcdmath I think we can delete all our comments now.